# App script: Add column of values based on the alignment of 2 columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create an app script function for GoogleSheet that takes as argument a specific column in the tab where the function is being called (`col1align`), a column in another tab (`col2align`), and a another column in the same second tab (`col2add`)

The function compares the values in the columns to align (`col1align` and `col2align`),
and if they match, copy the value of `col2add` in the column where the function is being called.

The `col1align` column is supposed to contain the same values as `col2align` but with duplicates.

---

This is an example of the first tab (TITLE would be the `col1align`

| TITLE | empty column where the function is called |
| --- | --- |
| title1 |  |
| title2 |  |
| title1 |  |

---

This is an example of the second tab (TITLE = `col2align`, ID = `col2add`)

| TITLE | ID |
| --- | --- |
| title1 | 1 |
| title2 | 2 |
| title3 | 3 |

---

The goal would be to have the values of the ID column pasted into the column where the function is being called, like that:

| TITLE | =alignCol(TITLE, tab2!TITLE, tab2!ID) |
| --- | --- |
| title1 | 1 |
| title2 | 2 |
| title1 | 1 |

I have made several attempts, but as I don't really know how to debug apps scripts, it has fail!

```js
function alignCol(col1align, col2align, col2add) {
  /**
   * Eg: col1align = "E"
   *     col2align = "tab2!E"
   *     col2add   = "tab2!F"
   */
  // Get data from col1align
  const col1align = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(`${col1align}:${col1align}`).getValues();

  let tab2;
  tab2, col2align = col2align.split("!")[0];
  col2add = col2add.replace(`${tab2}!`, "");

  // Get data from tab2
  const tab2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(tab2);
  const col2align = tab2.getRange(`${col2align}:${col2align}`).getValues();
  const col2add = tab2.getRange(`${col2add}:${col2add}`).getValues();

  const currentCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  const currentCol = "G"          // HOW TO GET COLUMN OF THE CURRENT CELL?

  // Iterate through col1
  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < col1align.length; rowIndex++) {
    const currentVal = col1align[rowIndex];

    if (col2Align.includes(currentVal)){
      const val2add = col2add[rowIndex];
      // add value to paste in column
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rowIndex, currentCol).setValue(col2addVal);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XLOOKUP doesn't work for you or you need them actually copied? If you put this in the first cell of your target column you can use, changing the names to the actual column ranges:

```
=INDEX(XLOOKUP(TITLE, tab2!TITLE, tab2!ID,,0))
```

Comment: Well indeed this is a a much simpler solution than what I was trying to do! Thank you a lot it worked as a charm